# <bytes> to escaped <str> Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, unicode

Currently, I have *Python 2.7* code that receives `<str>` objects over a socket connection. All across the code we use `<str>` objects, comparisons, etc. In an effort to convert to *Python 3*, I've found that socket connections now return `<bytes>` objects which requires us to change all literals to be like `b'abc'` to make literal comparisons, etc. This is a lot of work, and although it is apparent why this change was made in *Python 3* I am curious if there are any simpler workarounds.

Say I receive `<bytes> b'\xf2a27'` over a socket connection. Is there a simple way to convert these `<bytes>` into a `<str>` object with the same escapes in *Python 3.6*? I have looked into some solutions myself to no avail.

```
a = b'\xf2a27'.decode('utf-8', errors='backslashescape')
```

Above yields `'\\xf2a27'` with `len(a) = 7` instead of the original `len(b'\xf2a27') = 3`. Indexing is wrong too, this just won't work but it seems like it is headed down the right path.

```
a = b'\xf2a27'.decode('latin1')
```

Above yields `'òa27'` which contains Unicode characters that I would like to avoid. Although in this case `len(a) = 5` and comparisons like `a[0] == '\xf2'` work, but I'd like to keep the information escaped in representation if possible.

Is there perhaps a more elegant solution that I am missing?

Comment: Why do you think you want a `str`?

Comment: @StephenRauch: I don't think they do - they just don't want to rewrite all string literals into bytes literals. Unfortunately, that's the only sane course of action. (Search and replace?)

Comment: @Amadan, yes exactly.  The question was socratic in nature.

Comment: @StephenRauch What Amadan said is entirely the reason, but I am looking to make sure that I don't miss a simpler solution before the fun begins.

Comment: Python 3 strings *are* Unicode strings; by definition, you cannot avoid Unicode characters in Python 3 strings. If you want to avoid non-ASCII characters in favor of backslash escapes, that's doable; but really, if you do that, you are simply digging yourself deeper into the bug-riddled pit that was the reason this was changed from Python 2. The sane solution is to use `bytes` to represent bytes - that's precisely what this separate data type is for.

Answer (score 5):

You really have to think about what the data you receive represents and Python 3 makes a strong point in that direction. There's an important difference between a string of bytes that actually represent a collection of bytes and a string of (abstract, unicode) characters.

You may have to think about each piece of data individually if they can have different representations.

Let's take your example of `b'\xf2a27'` which in its raw form you receive from the socket is just a string of 4 bytes: `0xf2`, `0x61`, `0x32`, `0x37` in hex or `242`, `97`, `50`, `55` in decimal.

1. Let's say you actually want 4 bytes out of that. You could either keep it as a byte string or convert it into a `list` or `tuple` of bytes if that serves you better:

   ```
   raw_bytes = b'\xf2a27'

   list_of_bytes = list(raw_bytes)

   tuple_of_bytes = tuple(raw_bytes)

   if raw_bytes == b'\xf2a27':
       pass

   if list_of_bytes == [0xf2, 0x61, 0x32, 0x37]:
       pass

   if tuple_of_bytes == (0xf2, 0x61, 0x32, 0x37):
       pass
   ```
2. Let's say this actually represents a 32-bit integer in which case you should convert it into a Python `int`. Choose whether it is encoded in little or big endian byte order and make sure you pick the correct one of signed vs. unsigned.

   ```
   raw_bytes = b'\xf2a27'

   signed_little_endian, = struct.unpack('<i', raw_bytes)
   signed_little_endian = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes, byteorder='little', signed=True)

   unsigned_little_endian, = struct.unpack('<I', raw_bytes)
   unsigned_little_endian = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes, byteorder='little', signed=False)

   signed_big_endian, = struct.unpack('>i', raw_bytes)
   signed_big_endian = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes, byteorder='big', signed=True)

   unsigned_big_endian, = struct.unpack('>I', raw_bytes)
   unsigned_big_endian = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes, byteorder='big', signed=False)

   if signed_litte_endian == 926048754:
       pass
   ```
3. Let's say it's actually text. Think about what encoding it comes in. In your case it cannot be UTF-8 as `b'\xf2'` would be a byte string that cannot be correctly decoded as UTF-8. If it's latin1 a.k.a. iso8859-1 and you're sure about it, that's fine.

   ```
   raw_bytes = b'\xf2a27'

   character_string = raw_bytes.decode('iso8859-1')

   if character_string == '\xf2a27':
       pass
   ```

   If your choice of encoding was correct, having a `'\xf2'` or `'ò'` character inside the string will also be correct. It's still a single character. `'ò'`, `'\xf2'`, `'\u00f2'` and `'\U000000f2'` are just 4 different ways to represent the same **single** character in a (unicode) string literal. Also, the len will be 4, not 5.

   ```
   print(ord(character_string[0]))       # will be 242
   print(hex(ord(character_string[0])))  # will be 0xf2

   print(len(character_string))          # will be 4
   ```

   If you actually observed a length of 5, you may have observed it at the wrong point. Perhaps after encoding the character string to UTF-8 or having it implicitly encoded to UTF-8 by printing to a UTF-8 Terminal.

   Note the difference of the number of bytes output to the shell when changing the default I/O encoding:

   ```
   PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python3 -c 'print(b"\xf2a27".decode("latin1"), end="")' | wc -c
   # will output 5

   PYTHONIOENCODING=latin1 python3 -c 'print(b"\xf2a27".decode("latin1"), end="")' | wc -c
   # will output 4
   ```

Ideally, you should perform your comparisons **after** converting the raw bytes to the correct data type they represent. That makes your code more readable and easier to maintain.

As a general rule of thumb, you should always convert raw bytes to their actual (abstract) data type as soon as you receive them. Then keep it in that abstract data type for processing as long as possible. If necessary, convert it back to some raw data on output.